# email for program installed on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp

I am a college professor. My university's entire network is hosted by AWS. We have installed a program called WebWork for students to do and submit online homework. This program includes an email feature, that allows students to send an email message that automatically includes the problem they are working on to their instructor by clicking on a button. But we cannot get this feature to work. We used to have the same program on our own server before we moved to AWS, and the email was working fine.
There is a site.conf file with the line
$mail{smtpServer} = '';
that apparently needs to be filled in, but I don't know what to use for it.

Comment: It seems that you need to set that to the email server SMTP address. Is there any other configuration related to SMTP, like port, auth, etc.? Also, si there any error log you can share?

Comment: I have tried using 
$mail{smtpServer} = 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
and then after clicking on "Send message", the browser will return the error (after about one minute)
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request
Reason: Error reading from remote server
Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server at webwork.xula.edu Port 443

Comment: If instead I leave $mail{smtpServer} = '' 
blank, it will immediately return the error:
Failed to send message: invalid hosts in Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP constructor at /usr/share/perl5/Email/Sender/Transport/SMTP.pm line 76.

Comment: @Valerio Don’t worry about a single downvote, however adding the above information you’ve put in the comment in the question would point to the fact that you have indeed researched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your network is hosted on AWS, it doesn’t automatically grant you access to Amazon's SMTP servers.

You need to create a [verified identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/verify-addresses-and-domains.html) in [SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) for the domain/email address you want to use to send email from, before you can then [generate & use the SMTP credentials AWS provide you](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ses-set-up-connect-smtp) in your application.

You will need access to the AWS console to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the information, and just to be clear, I imagine having remote access to the server where the program is installed is not the same thing as having access to the AWS console, right? I imagine there is an AWS account that the university is using and I will need to ask to have access to the credentials for that account.

Comment: Yes, yes and yes :)

Comment: @Valerio To confirm, I assume the SMTP server listed in the options is no longer existent post the migration to AWS?

Comment: I think the SMTP server we were using before the migration is no longer available. But we are all using the same email address as before the migration (ending in .edu).  I read somewhere that in order to send email from AWS one can use an smtp such as email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com or a similar one. But I am guessing this is just one of Amazon's servers that you referred to in your answer, for which I first need to create a verified identity.

Comment: Okay in that case yes. You probably already have a full domain wide verification in place; check that and if so, just get the right SMTP credentials.